# How to enable a disabled JSP button in Java?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, button

I want to have something like this:

```
public void setButton(){
     document.getElementById('scan').disabled=false; 
}
```

scan is the ID of the button in the JSP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are dealing here is **html and javascript**  and **not java**. Java based systems at the server will **generate the html/css/js** based code (*after executing the JSP*) and send it to browser. For enable/disabling and disabling the  buttons, use javascript.

Not sure what you use case is, but you can use following [javascript code](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp) code to enable/disable the buttons

```
document.getElementById("scan").disabled = true;
```

This can be called on any event (like page load etc)..

**EDIT:**
In light of *new requirement* (Capture USB events), this may not be as straightforward as it seemed. I would suggest following approach.

1. Write a [signed Java Applet](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~lsiden/tutorials/signed-applet/signed-applet.html). This Applet will use some USB interfacing APIs (e.g [jUSB](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-usb.html)) to listen to the USB plugin events.
2. Then, from this Applet use [Applet Javascript interaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/invokingJavaScriptFromApplet.html)  to call the javascript function to enable the button (assuming that the button is disabled when the page loaded).

So it works as follows

- When you hit the URL, browser loads the page and Applet (with Scan button disabled by default)
- You plugin the USB device
- Java code in the applet listens to this event
- The listener calls the Javascript function in the page which enables the Scan button.

Comment: public void setButton() is in a java class. I want to do this because I have an event listener that when a USB is plugged, this function will be called inside the listener and the button will be enabled.

Comment: @pmark019 You can't. JSP is server-side, JSP page are compiled **before** the browser receives the generated HTML, so JSP methods will not work after the browser receives the output from server, you need something that can work client-side, you need Javascript.

Comment: Aw...Is it possible to reload a JSP page in java?

Comment: @pmark019 Yes, just use [response#sendRedirect(String location)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String))

Comment: You should have put these requirements int he question which will make it much clearer. What you are aiming is not very straightforward. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 0):

All the HTML in JSP compiles on server side   and comes to `Client`.

If you want to do something you need to make a request.

You can do it directly with html in your jsp

```
<input type="button" name=myButton   id="scan"  value="disable" disabled>
```

If javascript

```
document.getElementById("scan").disabled=true;  //not false
```

Comment: I know about this but I want to do this in java because I have an action listener that when a USB is plugged, the application will set the button to enabled.

Comment: You cannot do it.You have make a request.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use this

```
document.getElementById("scan").disabled = true;
```

or jquery

```
$("#scan").disable = true;
```